# Chrome renders empty span before it's sibling

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, rendering

I've noticed that the empty span is rendered before it's sibling in Chrome.

E.g. in this snippet, when you point to the second span in dev tools, it will be shown before the "abc" span.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span>abc</span>
    <span></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/psimon/4sbt62pu/

In Firefox it's rendered correctly behind.

Why is that? Is there documentation/discussion that could shed some light?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> I've noticed that the empty span is rendered before it's sibling in Chrome.
>
> it will be shown before the "abc" span.

That's wrong. The second  is still rendered after the first one.
But because the display of first one is `inline`, so you saw the second one is above. If you set `display: block` for the first span, you will understand clearly it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how is this related to `display: block` . If you compare the result in Firefox and Chrome, the second element is displayed where I expect it, i.e. after the first one. But Chrome does not and until there's any text (even zero width), the second span is shown before the first one.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a Chrome bug. To resolve that, you can add &nbsp; to make SPAN not empty.

Comment: Right, that's what I was hoping for to find a description of the bug, but couldn't find it anywhere ;)